# What enterprise-class open source CMS has the steepest (easiest) learning curve for a programmers team?

Tags: php, drupal, content-management-system, joomla, typo3

As a company specialized in developing custom CMS, we have been asked to deploy a open source CMS in our next project.

We are free to choose a system. What would you recommend for a team familiar with MVC model and OOP in PHP5?

I was told that Drupal and TYPO3 are very hard at the beginning, so what are the other options? eZ Publish or Joomla maybe?

Comment: Do you really mean "steepest"?

Comment: Yeh what Draemon said - you deliberately want to make things difficult?  Hard!=Good.

Comment: yes, he means steepest because he wants it to be easy in the beginning. easy = steep (learning as a function of time)

Comment: it's a learning curve guys! the faster the learning, the steeper the curve!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/277618/whats-a-learning-curve-and-why-is-steep-not-hard

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the people on your team are familiar with PHP then Drupal should not be difficult at all for them.  There are a few conventions that Drupal follows for creating hooks which are unique to it but are implemented consistently in core so once they are learned your team will be able to write module code that can control pretty much any aspect of how the site works.

The main reason for Drupal's reputation of being hard to learn is the large number of options in the administration screen, but if someone is serious about creating and maintaining a proper site this shouldn't be enough to turn them off of Drupal.

Comment: This may not be the answer I was expecting to receive but it's the best so far :)

Comment: I would choose Drupal too!

also don't forget the [Drupal Learning Curve](http://buytaert.net/drupal-learning-curve)

Answer (score 3):

If you're looking for an enterprise-class CMS I would not even mention joomla.
I see that you're not aware of [Silverstripe](http://www.silverstripe.org). I recommend to check it out!

Comment: I loved the developer documentation and simplicity (yet enterprise readiness) of Silverstripe. But the 100% Ajax CMS looks kinda tricky, isn't the JS part hard to maintain?

Comment: what do you mean with AJAX CMS?

Comment: I used it as an adjective - I meant that the Silverstripe's admin panel is 100% Ajax-based. Is it easy to maintain, debug, etc? Is it cross-browser? My friend noticed some JS glitches on Opera (alert() showing some debug code in the demo).

Comment: good point, I don't know too well how easy it is to debug but the js bugs of the admin panel are quite often mentioned as a drawback of silverstripe.

Answer (score 0):

No.. not ezPublish.. A hell to learn. Too much strange configuration going on there.

Answer (score 0):

CMSMadeSimple by far has the nicest codebase ive stumbled myself. Ive also made one commercial site with Joomla. It has lots of documentation but personally ive found it to be quite poor.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand y ur looking for the hardest, but anyway

not particular for multipurpose, content rich websites, but i'll throw magento into the hard-list for ecommerce solutions (though u could build you entire enterprise site around it). Their anual support at £4k - £6K should knock ur pants off!

Comment: A "steep" graph of knowledge vs. time means a large increase in knowledge over a short period of time - a steeper curve indicates easier learning, not harder.

Comment: Thanks Dave. I've edited the title because it was confusing for some.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for an enterprise-class CMS I would not look at PHP templating CMS's (joomla, drupal etc), but look at a Java CMS (JSR-170) or plone.