# Should we use Jade or React as view engine in expressjs

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, pug

I am new to expressjs and started building a project with MERN Stack.

I am confused as which view engine should I use jade\pug, EJS, React.

I have already used jade to render pages with content from mongodb into the browser.
Should I use the backend to serve the content in json instead of rendering the whole page as HTML.

I also tried to implement https://github.com/reactjs/express-react-views
so that I can use React to render page from server.
But there are some problems with 'express-messages' and 'connect-flash' npm packages.

Answer (score 5):

In my humble opinion, **it depends on your preference**. Actually it doesn't matter which template/view engine you pick, as you're just learning and practicing.
Their learning curve is [steep](https://stackoverflow.com/a/277632/11330560).
You can even learn them for free by watching some quality youtube vids, and you'll get the whole picture.
They're just tools, nothing more.

*Personal opinion: To name two popular ones that I personally use: Pug (jade) and EJS.

EJS is without any fuss, keeping the appearance of a normal html file.*

---

There, you had your answer. **BUT**:

However, in reality, if you work for someone else or might be your own personal preference later, you will be dealing with API designs like: [REST and GraphQL](https://medium.com/codingthesmartway-com-blog/rest-vs-graphql-418eac2e3083).

It means your `view` is separated from server-side, which is a part of `MVC` architecture, leaving it to the client-side to deal with it, and that's where `RESTful/GraphQl API` provides the communication online between server and client.

---

So that means you have to pick a frontend framework, of popular ones, React, Angular, or Vue.
Picking a frontend framework is far better than leaving your `view` to some template engine. Not only more flexibility, but also makes you more desirable in market.

Since you're dealing with React already, as a MERN stack, and your personal preference is to have it all server side, `Next.js` would be a great option to try.

Even at the website meant for MERN Stack fellows (https://mern.io/), to quote:
*We recommend using Next.js for your React projects.*

> `Next.js` is basically React on server side, that allows you to build your View with a strong framework, instead of a template engine, with so much flexibility and power over it.

---

Since you're using express as a framework for Node.js, this article is useful for you to use Next.js with express:

[Building a server-rendered React app with Next.js & Express.js](https://blog.logrocket.com/how-to-build-a-server-rendered-react-app-with-next-express-d5a389e7ab2f/)

---

Some articles that will be interesting to you:

[Server Side Templates vs REST API and Javascript Front-End](https://nickjanetakis.com/blog/server-side-templates-vs-rest-api-and-javascript-front-end)

[Is there any reason to use server side rendering instead of HTTP API + JS Frontend? [closed]](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/366966/is-there-any-reason-to-use-server-side-rendering-instead-of-http-api-js-fronte)